# Morphisms of schemes are $\mathcal{O}-$modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

*The following might not be true and part of the purpose of this question is to verify my understanding so far.*

---

Let me start with a few statements:

- Since the sheafication of a presheaf only takes into account the stalks we can, by virtue of this and some abstract nonsense, **treat sheaves as presheaves upto local isomorphism**. (induced isomorphism on stalks). In other words $Sh(X)$ is the category $Prsh(X)$ localized at local isomorphism.
- Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space. By local ismorphism of modules (and using that prsheafs of modules form an abelian category) i've been able to verify that the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules is abelian whenever $X$ is a *scheme*. We deduce that **$\mathcal{O}_X$ modules on a scheme are just presheaves of modules upto local isomorphism (of modules!).**

> **Question:** Does $X$ have to be a scheme for the catregory of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules to be abelian?.
>
> **Question 2:** By the preceding discussion we deduce that "morally", all properties of $\mathcal{O}_X-$modules should be local. Could this view be potentially dangerous?

**Application**:

A morphism of scheme is a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ and natural transformation between the sheafs $f^\flat : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ such that induced maps on stalks are local.

- *Alternative definition:* A morphism of scheme is a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ together with a choice of $\mathcal{O}_Y-$module  structure on $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ that satisfies $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)} / m_{f(x)} = ((f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)})_{m_x}$ for all $x \in X$.

The category of $\mathcal{O}_Y-$modules is abelian so we have a corresponding $\mathcal{O}_Y-$module $Ker f$. By the alternative definition $Kerf=Ann(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an ideal sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$.

In case $f$ is a homeomorphism onto it's image we have the follwoing charactrizations:

- **$f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is simple (as a $\mathcal{O}_Y-$module) iff $f$ is a closed immersion.**
- **The restriction of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ to the image of $f$ is trivial (as an $\mathcal{O}_Y-$module) Iff $f$ is an open immersion.**

Is everything OK here?

Comment: You shouldn't need $X$ to be a scheme. I don't know localisation of categories so I can't help with the rest

Comment: Be careful when you said that sheafification of presheaves only takes into account stalks. That not entirely true. I mean, there are presheaves (even sheaves) with isomorphic stalks whose associated sheaves are not isomorphic. I agree with the fact that sheaves are the localization of presheaves at local isomorphism though. And I agree with Hoot : the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules form an abelian category on any spaces and any sheaves of rings (even on any ringed toposes).

Comment: @Roland You're right of course. *Upto local isomorphism* should mean upto morphisms that decesnd to isomorphisms on stalks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand a bit on your idea that $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$ is the localisation of $\operatorname{Psh}(X)$ at the multiplicative set $S$ of morphisms that induce isomorphisms on all stalks (even though this may not be your main question). A better way to put it is:

**Lemma.** Let $\mathscr C$ be the Serre subcategory of $\operatorname{Psh}(X)$ of presheaves $\mathscr F$ such that $\mathscr F_x = 0$ for all $x \in X$. Then $\operatorname{Psh}(X)/\mathscr C \cong \operatorname{Sh}(X)$.

**Remark.** Recall (see e.g. [this section of the Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02MN)) that quotients by Serre subcategories are special instances of localisations, despite their name 'quotient'.

Note that $\mathscr C$ is the kernel of the sheafification. This follows since sheafification preserves stalks, and a sheaf is zero if and only if all stalks are zero.

I will actually prove something more general:

**Lemma.** Let $\iota \colon \mathscr A \subseteq \mathscr B$ be an additive and fully faithful functor of abelian categories, and assume that $\iota$ has an exact left adjoint $(-)^\#$ (we say that $\mathscr A$ is an *exact reflective subcategory*¹). Let $\mathscr C$ be the kernel of $(-)^\#$. Then $\mathscr B/\mathscr C \cong \mathscr A$.

*Proof.* The universal property of the quotient by a Serre subcategory gives a functor $F \colon \mathscr B/\mathscr C \to \mathscr A$. Note that $(-)^\#$ is the identity on $\mathscr A$. Indeed, since $\iota$ is full, for any two $\mathscr F, \mathscr G \in \operatorname{ob} \mathscr A$, we have
$$\mathscr A(\mathscr F, \mathscr G) = \mathscr B(\iota \mathscr F, \iota \mathscr G) = \mathscr A((\iota \mathscr F)^\#, \mathscr G),$$
so by the Yoneda Lemma we conclude that $(\iota \mathscr F)^\# = \mathscr F$. As a consequence, the composition
$$\mathscr A \stackrel{(-)^\#}{\longrightarrow} \mathscr B \to \mathscr B/\mathscr C$$
gives a right inverse $G \colon \mathscr A \to \mathscr B/\mathscr C$ of $F$. To check that $G$ is also a left inverse, we have to prove that $\mathscr F$ becomes isomorphic to $\mathscr F^\#$ in $\mathscr B/\mathscr C$, for all $\mathscr F \in \operatorname{ob} \mathscr B$. Let $K$ and $C$ be the kernel and cokernel of the natural map $\mathscr F \to \mathscr F^\#$ respectively. We get an exact sequence
$$0 \to K \to \mathscr F \to \mathscr F^\# \to C \to 0.$$
By exactness of $(-)^\#$ and the fact that $(-)^\#$ is the identity on $\mathscr A$, we conclude that $K^\# = 0$ and $C^\# = 0$. But this means exactly that $\mathscr F \to \mathscr F^\#$ becomes an isomorphism in $\mathscr B/\mathscr C$. $\square$

¹I'm not completely sure what terminology to use here. *Reflective* means that the inclusion has a left adjoint, but we want the adjoint to be exact (i.e. preserve finite limits). However, I do not require $\iota$ to be exact (think about the inclusion of $\operatorname{Psh}(X)$ into $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$)!

Comment: Sounds great, I think I need to put some time into reading about serre subcategories to really appreciate this. Thanks for the input!

Comment: If you are already familiar with localisations, then it's not so hard to pick up. It's just a version suited specifically to abelian categories. You probably know some examples already; for example the category of abelian groups modulo the Serre subcategory of torsion groups is the category of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces (hey, this also follows from my Lemma above, if $(-)^\#$ denotes $ - \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$).